# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered ":"

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I got **SQLSyntaxErrorException**.

Here a short extract of the error trace.

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntaxfehler: Encountered ":" at line 1, column 40.
Error Code: 20000
Call: select * from book where price between :min59 and :max59
Query: ReadAllQuery(referenceClass=Book sql="select * from book where price between :min59 and :max59")
```

I called

```
createNativeQuery("select * from book where price between :min59 and :max59", Book.class)
```

Then I set the two parameter with

```
query.setParameter("min59", 20.0); query.setParameter("max59", 30.0);
```

The exception occurs during

```
query.getResultList();
```

Environment:

- EclipseLink 2.5.1
- Apache Derby 10.X

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Can you try setDouble instead of setParameter?

Comment: JPA only mandates numbered parameters for native queries. Some implementations (e.g DataNucleus) support it, but if you want portability then you use numbered parameters

Answer (score 0):

You use a native query so your query has to be like this "select * from book where price between ? and ?".

If you use a query (jpql) you can do mapping by name.

Here you have to mapp by the number of the parameter : 
query.setParameter(1, 20.0);
query.setParameter(2, 30.0);

EDIT: for named parameter "Using EclipseLink, you can specify a named parameter in a native query using the EclipseLink # convention." from http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/queries006.htm

Comment: Doesn't work native queries with named parameter? Where can I find information about that?

Comment: "Using EclipseLink, you can specify a named parameter in a native query using the EclipseLink # convention."